# Python login script whitelist

Tags: python, authentication, whitelist

I want to make a python script with a standard input if statement for the login but i dont want other people to sell my script with the login etc.
How would I prevent this?

In case you didn't understand the question fully. Here is a situation for it.
So I sell someone a python script of mine with the login and password for it but I don't want them to go and sell my script with the username and password that I gave to them. I want it to be that only the specific person can login etc almost like a whitelist for specific individuals. How would I be able to do this?

Comment: You can't. And if you give them the code, they don't even need a login and password...

Comment: Could you give a more clarity to your problem? As @ThierryLathuille has mentioned, if you give the code to the person this is not going to work.

Comment: The code would be obfuscated of course